# Gettext .po files under version control

Tags: git, version-control, diff, gettext, po-file

Currently using Gettext on a project and the .po files are nicely kept
under version control.

PO files of course contain translations, but in addition to that they
also contain some metadata - information about the exact files and
line numbers where the translatable strings are located.

The problem is that each time you update the PO files the metadata
changes a whole lot more than the actual translations.  This makes it
really hard to later see from version control diff what actually was
changed - you just see a myriad of changes to file names and line
numbers.  Like that:

```
- #: somefile.js:43
- #: somefile.js:45
- #: somefile.js:118
+ #: somefile.js:203
+ #: somefile.js:215
  msgid "Translate me please"
  msgstr "Tõlgi mind palun"

- #: somefile.js:23
- #: somefile.js:135
+ #: otherfile.js:23
+ #: otherfile.js:135
  msgid "Note"
  msgstr "Märkus"

- #: andThatFile.js:18
  #: orThisFile.js:131
- msgid "Before I was like this"
- msgstr "Selline olin ma enne"
+ msgid "I happen to be changed"
+ msgstr "Paistab, et mind muudeti"
```

Of course, a simple fix would be to just disable the generation of
filename/linenumber comments in xgettext output.  But I actually find
those file names to be quite useful hints when translating.

I surely cannot be the only one who doesn't like the diffs of his PO files.
Suggestions?

Comment: You could also try splitting that change into 2 changes: one that updates the metadata and one that that updates the translations. Then you could ignore the metadata changes.

Comment: If you do want to disable generating the file names and line numbers, just pass `--no-location` to `xgettext` or to `msgmerge`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

A simple fix would be to apply a grep filter to remove comment metadata from the viewed diff.  You can either do this to the *output* of the version control diff utility:

```
myVersionControl diff REV1 REV2 filea | grep -v '^..#'
```

or you may be able to instruct the version control diff utility to ignore these before it makes the comparison, which will likely result in a more reliable and prettier output:

I don't know what version control system you use, but git (for example) allows you to preprocess the input to diff *and remove the comment lines* for certain file types (thanks VonC), see `man gitattributes` and search for *Performing text diffs of binary files*.  Here's the body of a sample script to save as `/usr/local/bin/strippocomments` which will do that:

```
grep -v '^#:' $1
```

You can then tell git to use this script to preprocess po files, by adding the following to the file `.git/info/attributes` in your repository:

```
*.po diff=podiff
```

and to the file `.git/config` in your repository:

```
[diff "podiff"]
    textconv = /usr/local/bin/strippocomments
```

Using git diff should then not include any lines starting with `#:`.

Note that the diffs generated from `git diff` using this approach should not be used for patching - but `git format-patch` will still use the default diff, so patches generated for emailing will still be ok.

Comment: It seems that my git doesn't support --ignore-matching-lines option. Using version 1.6.5.2

Comment: But filtering the diff with grep really does produce a lot cleaner output. How came I didn't think about this by myself? Of course this doesn't help when I view the diff through a something else than console interface, but it indeed solves most of the problem.

Comment: okay, I took a stab that it would work based upon the fact that lots of stuff I hoped would work in the past actually did!  However, git diff is very flexible and can probably be made to do it.

Comment: I want to note that regexp should be '^#:' not just '^#' because there is other forms as '#,fuzzy' which you need to see actually.

Comment: Thanks for the tip of using `textconv` - that's a lot better than using `command = mypodiff`.

Comment: Alright, I think your answers were the most helpful ones. Although great thanks for all the others who botherered to answer too. Here's your 150 points :)

Comment: I have tried several things, but this was the only one that worked( to preprocess the input to diff and remove the comment lines for certain file types ). thank you @AlexBrown

Answer (score 24):

The `gitattributes`/`textconv` approach is the right way to go.  I'd like to offer a better solution regarding to tools to do the preprocessing.

In `.gitattributes`:

```
*.po    diff=po
```

In `.gitconfig`:

```
[diff "po"]
    textconv=msgcat --no-location --no-wrap --sort-output
```

`msgcat` from the gettext package is a useful tool there.  It has a number of options you can play with.  The option `--no-location` is especially what you want to filter out the line number differences.  The other options might be useful if `xgettext` and/or `msgmerge` and/or your editor keep reformatting the strings in annoying ways.  (In that case, it would also be good to pass those same options to those tools, and reconfigure your editor.)

Comment: Be aware that unlike `.gitattributes` and `.gitignore`, `.gitconfig` *in your source tree* won't be parsed by Git. You have to use either `~/.gitconfig` or `.git/config`.

Comment: You can have e.g. Makefile with target `gitconfig` which runs `git config diff.po.textconv "msgcat --no-location --no-wrap --sort-output"` and every developer must run `make gitconfig` once for their working directory.

Answer (score 8):

GNU gettext package has numerous useful utilities to perform various tasks with PO files.  There is msgcmp to compare two PO files, msgcomm to select common/unique messages, msgattrib to select/filter/transform existing PO files. Depends on what you actually need from diff of PO file, I think you need to use either msgattrib or msgcomm.

If you need to just compare two PO files without comments about file/line then simple script to grep and save in temp dir your old and new PO files would be sufficient.

Answer (score 7):

You could look at the different options offered by a [custom diff a .gitattribute file](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_generating_diff_text), like specifying a special diff for po files

```
[diff "mypodiff"]
    command = mypodiff
*.po   diff=mypodiff
```

with `mypodiff` a script calling any `diff` tool able to filter out the line that you wa wnt

Comment: Thanks, managed to get this working. A bit tricky part was getting the argument order correct for the external diff command.

Comment: BTW, is there a way to have the option `--ext-diff` always on when running commands `git-show` and `git-log` (and possibly others). The external diff command is applied to .po files when using `git-diff`, but I rarely use that command, for others I need to add `--ext-diff` option.

Comment: I would say: `git alias` could help you there. by defining aliases, you could add the relevant option to those commands.

Comment: Thanks for your hint, helped me fix my submission.